# How can I improve my spaCy model to perfectly recognise coordinates?

Tags: nlp, annotations, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I trained a model for custom named entity recognition by using wonderful prodigy but It can not recognise coordinate in this:

"But the sun is 7° LONG 51’ 24“ removed from opposition  to Mars "

as you see it gives me:

[7° LONG 51’ 24“]

but it should be like this

[7°  51’ 24“ LONG]
can anyone help me why it is so?

more detail:

I have done an annotation by regex for labels as following: Date, Time, Coordinate, then I trained my custom named entity recognition using Prodigy

https://prodi.gy/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyLDpBRCxARIsAEENsrLs2bbv7QT-d7lq88ZHkYaxPjI9L3aR23uRQGgWOBV1spM5WGV_LrIaAv6pEALw_wcB

I followed this step  for each label first I

1-edit annotation by this command (for instance for longitude)

```
python -m prodigy ner.manual an_ner_date_time_02 en_core_web_sm AN_NER_DATE_TIME_01.jsonl  --label LONG
```

to edit (by an annotator) my per-annotated data by regex.  Then I merged my dataset. the next stage was to build a model by

2-bulid a model (for all merged data)

```
python -m prodigy ner.batch-train data_merged_v06 en_core_web_sm --output Model_12 --n-iter 10 --eval-split 0.2 --dropout 0.2 --no-missing
```

question: 
how can I have better annotation regarding long,

So now I have a model which has this result:

```
BEFORE     0.008
Correct    36
Incorrect  4438
Entities   2802
Unknown    0


#          LOSS       RIGHT      WRONG      ENTS       SKIP       ACCURACY
01         110.744    1614       163        1683       0          0.908
02         98.563     1660       107        1719       0          0.939
03         98.472     1668       96         1724       0          0.946
04         96.250     1673       93         1731       0          0.947
05         96.192     1679       80         1730       0          0.955
06         96.108     1678       71         1719       0          0.959
07         94.347     1681       67         1721       0          0.962
08         96.472     1679       66         1716       0          0.962
09         98.936     1681       57         1711       0          0.967
10         96.175     1681       57         1711       0          0.967

Correct    1681
Incorrect  57
Baseline   0.008
Accuracy   0.967
```

It can annotate the data as you see here (click the link)

![annotation text]

(https://ibb.co/rtQm5B9)

![annotation text]

the problem is the model can not learn perfectly coordinate as you see 
7° LONG 51’ 24“ it should be
7°  51’ 24“ LONG

is wrongly  annotated (however It annotated by regex correct in the training set but by the model in the test set no!)

do you have any idea how to improve this?

second question, How can I use the result of ner for the classification of sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Since the named-entity you are trying to recognise is very specific, a coordinate, it's shape is well defined, why not go with pattern/rules, for instance a regular expression?

Comment: Many many thanks David for your responses, actually the plan was first to provide rule methods with regex, then we basically annotate all data, In order to have a Spacy model and maybe improve annotation (because after training model it can be reannotate by annotor in prodigy), we import the data in Prodigy (product of spaCY). But even s oRegex give us correct coordinate, after trianing the mdoel have some mistakes

Comment: But the regex already give you the correct coordinate, why not rely on the regex to find these LAT/LON and the statistical model for the other named-entities, you can use both, just a bit of soft. eng. and you can have your pipeline working with both.

Comment: I do not know how to use both approaches since I used "prodigy" to train a model based pre-annotated labels by regex.

Comment: from your main code you call the prodigy-based model, and also apply a regex, merge results at the end.

Comment: you are saying that I should make a model by all label excepts the "LONG" then saved the data, and also merged the annotated data from regex  for only "LONG" with the result.  is it possible? could you please send me an example or link, I am not sure how to save the data after making a mode in a foramt of prodigy

Comment: could you please elaborate this part for me?

Answer (score 0):

here you can see the regex can perfectly annotate the LONG (I test it in regex101.com)

```
regex_patterns = [
                  re.compile(r"\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\"|”|“]\s?[A-Z][a-z.]+"   #LONG in format 
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]\s?\s?[A-Z][a-z.]+"
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\"|”|“]"
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?\d{1,2}\s?[\'|’]"
                              "|\d{1,3}\s?°\s?[A-Z][a-z.]+")           
]
```

but I do not know why after training there si some mistakes (error it is not problem, But I am wondering why it gives part of span to me)

as you here: 
[image]

like 
in the third line:  [8 37 is annotated but -------->8 37 Gemini] is correct 
in the fourth line   [7 is annotated but ---------->7 51 21 ]is correct

another annotation is ok, even for TIME however we have 10h 50m  which look like of structure of long (more than one word) but it is correct, I really do not know what is the problem!